# The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to run this JPQL request but I'm getting this error: The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

```
                "SELECT c "
                + "FROM CoursJoursDeviseBb c "
                + "WHERE codeDevise = :codedevise "
                + "AND dateCours = (SELECT MAX(dateCours) FROM CoursJoursDeviseBb "
                + "WHERE codeDevise = :codedevise) "
```

Comment: You forgot some white spaces between your clauses.

Comment: i edit the code, still doesn't work :/

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is...

Comment: [94, 103] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression.
[129, 129] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

> he expression is not a valid conditional expression

Thanks to JB Nizet we found missing space.

> An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration

Try to qualify your table in subquery such as

```
     + "AND dateCours = (SELECT MAX(dateCours) FROM CoursJoursDeviseBb c2 "
            + " WHERE c2.codeDevise = :codedevise) "
```

to distinguish between two uses of table.

Comment: Done, now i have this exception : [94, 103] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression.

Comment: Looks like i too have forgotten space. Fixed now